# SharePoint Online Modern UI site is slow when using IE11

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, performance, modern

We are using the SharePoint Online Modern UI site.
It doesn't matter if my browser is Chrome or Edge, but IE11 takes a long time to display the list etc.
Does anyone have this kind of experience?
How did you solve it?

Appreciate any ideas\Points.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of IE? We, like many other companies, are still having to support IE11 due to legacy applications. It's just horribly slow and we've had to accept it. Where possible I recommend my users to just use Chrome or Edge since we support those.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The version is IE11.